# Does C++ allow normal parameters after variadic template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, standards, variadic-templates

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard), the following code is legal:

```
lock_guard( MutexTypes&... m, std::adopt_lock_t t );
```

However, the following code cannot be compiled with clang 3.8 (-std=c++1z):

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&..., bool)
{}

int main()
{
    f(1, 2, 3, true); // error! see below for details.
}
```

> ```
> 1>main.cpp(59,2): error : no matching function for call to 'f'
> 1>          f(1, 2, 3, true);
> 1>          ^
> 1>  main.cpp(54,6) :  note: candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
> 1>  void f(Args&&..., bool)
> 1>       ^
> 1>  1 error generated.
> ```

**Does C++ allow normal parameters after variadic parameters?**

Comment: My compiler is clang 3.8. gcc 6.2 fails too.

Comment: Note that with the `lock_guard` example, it's a class constructor, so all the template arguments are known beforehand, rather than trying to deduce them from the function call arguments.

Comment: It is C++17, not C++11.

Comment: To be precise: variadic parameters is a feature inherited from C and they must be the last ones. You are asking about parameter packs, which were introduced in C++11.

Comment: @tad can you please provide a proof or reference for the statement that the C feature is called "variadic parameters"?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I found this in cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments "Note: this is different from a function parameter pack expansion, which is indicated by an ellipsis that is a part of a parameter declarator, rather than an ellipsis that appears as a parameter on its own." It is possible that I misunderstood something here or that the sentence is wrong, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function declaration in your code is valid, however *deduction* does not work properly for such function templates. Note that the following code is well-formed, and instantiates the specialization `void f(int, int, int, bool)`:

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&..., bool) {}

int main() {
    f<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, true);
}
```

Note that in C++17, `MutexTypes...` are the template parameters to the class itself:

```
template <class... MutexTypes> class lock_guard;
```

so they are known and do not need to be deduced. Note that the constructor with `adopt_lock_t` cannot be used for C++17 class template argument deduction since the `adopt_lock_t` argument occurs after the parameter pack. If the committee had been prescient in C++11, they would have put the `adopt_lock_t` argument at the beginning rather than at the end, but alas, it is too late now.

Comment: Not too late, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock/scoped_lock