# Function parameter pack specialization

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo(T , Ts ... )
{
}

template <typename ... Ts, typename T>
void bar(T , Ts ... )
{
}

int main()
{
  foo<int, char>(1, 'c'); // well formed
  foo(1, 'c');

  // bar<int, char>(1, 'c'); // ill formed
  bar(1, 'c');
}
```

Why does explicitly specializing the template parameter function **not** work in the second case (`bar`)? It's obvious that the reason is that the parameter pack comes first in the argument-list, but still... why?

In the end of the day both cases work fine with implicit deduction. Explicitly specifying the arguments should only make it easier for the compiler.

*To the person who flagged it for [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269453/does-c-allow-normal-parameters-after-variadic-template-parameters), I am not talking about "normal parameters" if anything like that even exists. Also I am not asking whether I can place a parameter pack before a paremeter, I am asking why I cannot explicitly specify the template arguments when pack comes first in the argument-list.*

Comment: You can only deduce a variadic parameter if it's the last parameter. See the linked question.

Comment: In both cases the variadic **argument** is the last parameter. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: You would need to reverse the order of your arguments.  `bar<int,char>` means the char is first (because of the way you wrote the template), and you're passing it second.

Comment: `bar<char>(1, 'c');` works too.

Comment: `Ts...` is "greedy", so you cannot specify `T`, `T` has to be deduced.

Comment: @TimRoberts https://godbolt.org/z/o1zzx9oMG what?

Comment: @Jarod42 essence of the question is still there though, not allowed to explicitly specialize the pack args? (just in function param packs; and not template param packs)

Comment: You can explicit parameter pack (as above example `bar<char>(1, 'c')`), but in `bar<char, int>`, `Ts...` = `{char, int}`, T cannot be provided, and so you have `bar(T, char, int)` but you call it with only 2 parameters `1, 'c'`.

Comment: No it's not in the second case the variadic parameter is the first template parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: order in `template<..>` is not important for deduction possibility, it is order in function arguments `f(Ts... non deducibles, T)`/`g(T, Ts... deducible)`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yet `bar(1, 'c');` still deduces it. You still fail to see the lack of relevance to the linked question?

Answer (score 0):

A parameter pack is "greedy", so when you put `Ts` first and then explicitly specify template arguments as `int, char`, the pack gobbles up all the arguments specified, *i.e.*, `Ts` is `int, char` and `T` has not been specified yet. `T` is deduced from the type of the first argument, but that means the resulting declaration of `bar` has parameter-type-list `int, int, char`, since `int` was deduced for `T` but `int, char` was explicitly specified for `Ts`. So this particular specialization of `bar` requires 3 arguments but you've only provided 2.